# the listview items are not displayed in the order of entry

Tags: android, listview

I try to implement this [Android TextHighlighter](https://github.com/xeoh/TextHighlighter)  in my application but the listview displays the data in a disordered way. That is, the entries do not appear in the list according to the order established in the code. All the elements of my listview are displayed but not in the desired order. I want to display my items in the exact order in which I entered them, ie the oldest entry is the first item in the list.

thats is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
    private static final int DEFAULT_FG_COLOR = Color.RED;

    private TextHighlighter textHighlighter = new TextHighlighter()
      .setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_BG_COLOR)
      .setForegroundColor(DEFAULT_FG_COLOR);

    private TextHighlighter.Matcher matcher = 
    TextHighlighter.CASE_INSENSITIVE_MATCHER;

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    QuoteListAdapter adapter = new QuoteListAdapter(QUOTES, textHighlighter);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    EditText searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_text);
    searchText.addTextChangedListener(searchTextWatcher);

    EditText fgColorText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fg_color_text);
    fgColorText.addTextChangedListener(fgColorTextWatcher);

    EditText bgColorText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bg_color_text);
    bgColorText.addTextChangedListener(bgColorTextWatcher);

    CheckBox boldText = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bold_text);
    boldText.setOnCheckedChangeListener(boldChangedListener);

    CheckBox italicText = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.italic_text);
    italicText.setOnCheckedChangeListener(italicChangedListener);
     }

    private TextWatcher searchTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      String text = s.toString();

      if (text.isEmpty()) {
        QuoteListAdapter adapter = new QuoteListAdapter(QUOTES, textHighlighter);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
      } else {
        HashMap<String, String> filtered = new HashMap<>();

        for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : QUOTES.entrySet()) {
          if (matcher.isHighlightable(entry.getKey(), text)
              || matcher.isHighlightable(entry.getValue(), text)) {
            filtered.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
          }
        }
        QuoteListAdapter adapter = new QuoteListAdapter(filtered, textHighlighter);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

      textHighlighter.highlight(s.toString(), matcher);
    }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
     };

      private TextWatcher fgColorTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      if (s.toString().isEmpty()) {
        textHighlighter.setForegroundColor(DEFAULT_FG_COLOR);
      } else {
        try {
          int color = Color.parseColor("#" + s.toString());
          textHighlighter.setForegroundColor(color);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
          textHighlighter.resetForegroundColor();
        }
      }
      textHighlighter.invalidate(matcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    };

    private TextWatcher bgColorTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      if (s.toString().isEmpty()) {
        textHighlighter.setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_BG_COLOR);
      } else {
        try {
          int color = Color.parseColor("#" + s.toString());
          textHighlighter.setBackgroundColor(color);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
          textHighlighter.resetBackgroundColor();
        }
      }
      textHighlighter.invalidate(matcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    };

    private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener boldChangedListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      textHighlighter.setBold(isChecked);
      textHighlighter.invalidate(matcher);
     }
     };

     private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener italicChangedListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      textHighlighter.setItalic(isChecked);
      textHighlighter.invalidate(matcher);
    }
    };

    private class QuoteListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<HashMap.Entry<String, String>> quotes;
    private TextHighlighter textHighlighter;

    QuoteListAdapter(HashMap<String, String> quotes, TextHighlighter textHighlighter) {
      this.quotes = new ArrayList<>(quotes.entrySet());
      this.textHighlighter = textHighlighter;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return QUOTES.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
      return quotes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      Context context = parent.getContext();

      if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView quoteTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quote);
        textHighlighter.addTarget(nameTextView);
        textHighlighter.addTarget(quoteTextView);
      }

      TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
      TextView quoteTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quote);
      nameTextView.setText(quotes.get(position).getKey());
      quoteTextView.setText(quotes.get(position).getValue());
      textHighlighter.invalidate(matcher);

      return convertView;
    }
    }

    private static final HashMap<String, String> QUOTES;
    static
    {
    QUOTES = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      QUOTES.put("Edsger Dijkstra" + Integer.toString(i),
          "If debugging is the process of removing software bugs, then programming must be the " +
              "process of putting them in.");

      QUOTES.put("Linus Torvalds" + Integer.toString(i),
          "Most good programmers do programming not because they expect " +
              "to get paid or get adulation by the public, but because it is fun to program.");

      QUOTES.put("Chris Heilmann" + Integer.toString(i),
          "Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet.");

      QUOTES.put("Edward V Berard" + Integer.toString(i),
          "Walking on water and developing software from a " +
              "specification are easy if both are frozen.");

      QUOTES.put("Brian Kernighan" + Integer.toString(i),
          "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the " +
              "first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, " +
              "by definition, not smart enough to debug it.");

      QUOTES.put("Rick Osborne" + Integer.toString(i),
          "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code " +
              "will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.");

      QUOTES.put("Nathan Myhrvold" + Integer.toString(i),
          "Software sucks because users demand it to.");
    }
  }
}
```

What can be disturbing in this code? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
  QuoteListAdapter adapter = new QuoteListAdapter(filtered, textHighlighter);
```

you init "filtered" from [hashmap](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp) but hashmap maintains no order.
so when you iterate through the keys you don't get the order you expect.

Comment: either sort "filtered" by the value you want or use a dataset that maintain order [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)